# imdecode fails to load the image

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I have an 1D image data in the following format

```
cv::Mat TestIm(400,400,CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar(0));
cv::putText(TestIm,"Hello !",cv::Point(100,200),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,cv::Scalar(255));
QByteArray ImData = QByteArray((char *)TestIm.data,TestIm.total()); //this is 1D image data
```

Now suppose I want to get the original image from this data, I use the following code snippet :

```
 cv::Mat rawData  =  cv::Mat( 1, ImData.size(), CV_8UC1, ImData.data() );

 cv::Mat decodedImage  =  cv::imdecode( rawData , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
 if ( decodedImage.data == NULL )
 {
     qDebug()<<"Error in decompression !";
 }
```

As it is stated in opencv docs, it will guess the image dimension and creates the output. but in this case it always write

```
    "Error in decompression !"
```

what is wrong here ? I have used this code snippet many times in different projects but I don't know why it fails here !

if I change the second part to this assuming I know the image dimension it works :

```
  cv::Mat decodedImage = cv::Mat(400,400,CV_8UC1,ImData.data());
```

but I don't want this because in real scenarios I have an 1D array of image data (with unknown dimension) and I want to get the full 2D image.

I also prefer not to use third party libraries such as libjpeg. All I want is to use OpenCV to solve it.

I have OpenCV 3.0.0 and Qt 5.7 and my OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: cv::imdecode should afaik be used to decode some encoded image data, like a buffer with jpeg or png image data. If I understand it right, you've just plain rawdata saved to a 1D byteArray, I guess you can't "decode" it this way. However, if you still know the pixel format and image dimensions you can convert the raw buffer back to a Mat easily.

Comment: If you want to encode your image, you can use openCV cv::imencode. It will create a 1D byteArray of encoded data and stores the dimension information somewhere internally (e.g. in a jpeg header or sth.), however it will cost some computation time and depending on the codec it will or will not be lossy.

Comment: @Micka please write a complete answer. You were right 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone in the comments has mentioned these data (ImData variable in the code) are not encoded ! they are just some decoded pixel values !

In order to make cv::imdecode work, you have to encode the initial data to some known formats such as ".jpg" and then use the function to get the original data.

```
cv::Mat DecodedImage = TestIm;
std::vector<uchar> OutputBuffer;
cv::imencode(".jpg",DecodedImage,OutputBuffer);
cv::Mat rawData  =  cv::Mat( 1, OutputBuffer.size(), CV_8UC3, OutputBuffer.data() );
cv::Mat Output  =  cv::imdecode( cv::Mat(rawData) , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Comment: Sorry, I was waiting for the guy("Micka") to write the answer but he didn't do it in the last month so I wrote my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by using a known size, see this post for details:

[Opencv Mat conversion to QByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939872/opencv-mat-conversion-to-qbytearray)

Better solution is to serialize/parse data by using datastreams, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21473345/4297146

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand you can do that if you want to avoid fixing a value:

define:

```
struct memoryStruct {
char *memory;
size_t size;
};
```

before imdecode initialize:

```
memoryStruct temp;
temp.memory = NULL;
temp.size = 0;
```

assign temp to your QByteArray then call imdecode

```
cv::imgTmp = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1, temp.size, CV_8UC1, temp.memory), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

You can easily remove the use of the structure.